# Foursquare API does not return sights

Tags: foursquare

I'm trying to use the Foursquare API to get historic and other sights in an area, but it seems that I only get restaurants and clothing shops?

I've set "section" parameter to "sights", but it does not seem to have an effect. For example, this is for Brighton in the UK:

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/explore%3Fll%3D50.823422,-0.143058%26section%3Dsights%26sortByDistance%3D0

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this error. Are you still seeing this issue?

Comment: Yes, it's still the same. Check the above link - the venues in results such as Foodilitic, Bond Street Coffee, The Craft Beer Co., Gelato Gusto etc etc are not sights at all, they are all food & drink. Instead, there should be Brighton Pier, Brighton Dome, Brighton Marina, Brighton beach etc, all of which have a profile on 4fq

Comment: I've got the same problem, it simply doesn't work so I don't understand why the have documented this option if at the end it doesn't work...

Comment: Also having same issue...